# Is there a way to flip the functionality of the green full screen / maximize button?

Tags: macos, window-manager, fullscreen

As we all know, clicking the green traffic light button on the windows in mac osx enter the app into fullscreen mode.

Doing an Option + Click makes the window usually resizes to the to the maximum possible size.

I rarely use fullscreen, only for iTunes I think, and sometimes mail.

I use Option + Click all of the time.

My question is - is there a way to flip the functionality of the green button, so Click does the Option+Click function, and vice versa.

I'm on the latest Sierra.

Thanks.